# Change number of regions in Prism Shell

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-4, prism-5

[image]

Hi I am Using Prism 6 with unity. and navigation Similar to  [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/View-Switching%20Navigation_Desktop)

I want to change the number , shape and size of regions in my shell after user crosses a certain checks in my WPF app.for that I am using Data Template Selector  in shell.
1. Left side in image shows my application layout initially. [DataTemplate1]
2 Right side in image shows my application layout after some authentication[DataTemplate2].
3.In Shell.xaml.cs I am changing a flag(after authetication)and with help of Event aggregator, my Template selector returns proper template.[DataTemplate2]
4.  Here when in oneModule I am Trying use region defined in my DataTemplate2 I am getting an Exception.(Which was otherwise working fine, without using templates in shell)
            IRegion mainContentRegion = this._regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion];

An exception occurred while trying to create region objects. 
    - The most likely causing exception was:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Prism.Regions.Behaviors.RegionCreationException: An exception occurred while creating a region with name ''. The exception was: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Update1>> As i mentioned earlier I am using navigation sample provided here. [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/View-Switching%20Navigation_Desktop). when i debug it I found that just before navigation the region manager has few regoins in normal case
[image] but in my case (after templating shell) the region manager collection is empty(enumeration yeilded no results) I believe i need to fix my region collection after templating shell my region manager region collection getting reset. I need advice someone who is expert in Prism.

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to create a region without a name. Why change the number, shape and size of regions in your shell at runtime? Why not just navigate to another view that looks like what you need when authentication is complete? What you are trying seems overly complicated.

Comment: Is it Possible/good pratice to create Shell with DataTemplate/DataTemplateSelector?
 Making my View Adjustable is an option but that will come with a compromise of regions leaving its aspect ratio(say one of my new region need to be span across two region and vice-a-versa).why not to change my shell only when i am never gonna go back to previous regions once autheticated.

Comment: I haven't used DataTemplates in that capacity, so I can't say if it a good practice, or not. Using another view to show what you intend seems easier to me since DataTemplates I have worked with have been difficult to troubleshoot when it comes to layout.

Comment: I have fair bit of experience with WPF/Templateselectors and I am able to switch the template. the problem I am facing is with Prism Navigation. regionManager.RequestNavigate(LoginRegionNames.MainContentRegion, emailsViewUri);   "An exception occurred while trying to create region objects." Which works fine otherwise if I don't switch the template.

Comment: Are all the names of the regions in the email view (assuming you have some there) all named with unique names? Is it possible for you to have more than one email view in memory at the same time? If so, you may have to look into the idea of using scoped regions.

Comment: I found the reason why it is failing it because region in side dataTemplate does get added into the Region manager and we need to use regionAwareBehaviour.  http://southworks.com/blog/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/  now I am trying to get my design compatible with it.

Comment: Excellent! Well done, and good luck going forward.